# insertion sort algorithm using a second array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

Trying to understand the insertion sort algorithm..

My algorithm looks like this currently:

```
    void insertionSort(int *array, int N) {
        int value;
        int hole;
        int *array2;


        for (int i = 1; i < N - 1; i++) {
            value = array[i]; //next item to be inserted in array 2
            hole = i;
            while (hole > 0 && array[hole - 1] > value) {
                array[hole] = array[hole - 1];
                hole = hole - 1;
            }
            array[hole] = value;
        }
    }
```

My algorithm works for sorting arrays, however I now need to change it so that I build up a new sorted array (array2) one element at a time, rather than just working with the original array.

Is there a simple way to implement this given my completed algorithm? 
Thanks.

Comment: `int *array2 = new int[];` isn't valid C++.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following method:

```
int *array2 = calloc(N, sizeof(int));
for(var index = 0; index < N; index++)
{
   array2[index] = array[index];
}
```

and after that use array2 instead of array
then just change the prototype of your function to int *insertionSort
All remaining is to return array2 at the end of task
But be aware of memory leak: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak

Comment: what is calloc? and what does that for loop actually do?

Comment: This is C++, not SPARTAAAAAAA! Use `std::vector`, not `calloc` @Liam `calloc` is a C function to allocate and clear memory. Use it in C, and while there are edge cases in C++ where it makes sense, they are edge cases. Consider carefully before using it.

Comment: @user4581301 not to get off-topic but when would you calloc instead of new?

Comment: @Brandon off the top, I can't think of any. Any constrained environment that can't tolerate `std::bad_alloc` on a failed `new`, I probably wouldn't be using dynamic allocation at all or would be required to write in C. And if I was considering dynamic allocation that initialized the pool, the side benefits of `std::vector` almost always win even in high performance code.  Doesn't mean there aren't any cases, though.

Comment: @Liam calloc(number_of_blocks, size_of_blocks) occupy a part of memory and in fact that (for loop) copies "array" into "array2"

Comment: @user4581301 you are right! It can be a better idea